# How did the letter "v" come to represent the voiced labio dental fricative?

Tags: latin, orthography, evolution

When I learned Latin we were taught classical pronunciation. When it came to the letter "v" we were taught to pronounce it as /w/. It was also explained that many people (my parents, for example) had learned the ecclesiastical pronunciation in which the letter "v" is pronounced /v/ the same as it is in English.

It would probably helped if in all the texts we used did not use both characters ''u" and "v" to represent the same classical character. I never understood that there was no voiced labiodental fricative /v/ in classical Latin. I was always confused as to why Roman engravings always used "v" in place of "u."

When I later came to the realization that both English characters represented one Latin character I wondered why "Veni. Vidi. Vici." was not spelled "Ueni. Uidi. Uici." in the textbook as it should have been.

At some point the double "v" came to be used to differentiate between the consonant form of the Latin "v" and its vowel form. The consonant form, the voiced labiovelar approximant /w/ and the vowel form, the close back rounded vowel /u/ seem like similar enough phonemes to my ears that I can understand why they are the same character in Latin. The "u" is used for the /w/ sound often in English (especially following "q") and in Spanish. I also can see how the pointed form of the character, "v" could evolve into the rounded form, "u" in writing.

Where my confusion comes in is how the voiced labiodental fricative /v/ came to be assigned to the pointed "v." This caused centuries of scholars to basically mis-pronounce Latin. The same sound is represented by the pointed form, "v" in English. And even more confusing is how the double "v," which was created to differentiate /w/ from /u/, came to represent the voiced labiodental fricative /v/ in German. The /v/ sounds to my ears like a completely different phoneme unrelated to /u/ or /w/.

Comment: It's not unrelated. Development of [w] sounds to [v] has been quite common in the history of Indo-European languages.

Comment: @sumelic So this change has happened in other languages besides Latin? So it's probably not as far of a stretch as I'm thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phoneme /w/ in Latin underwent a phonetic change around the second half of the 1st century AD, though this was a low prestige sound change, becoming pronounced [β] and later [v]. Hence the letter  is usually pronounced [v] because that it how it was pronounced in later Latin. This is similar to the situation with the fricative pronunciation of Greek <φ θ χ>: classical pronunciation changed.

Comment: Are you sure it was a phonetic change and not phonemic?

Comment: Well, it was initially a phonetic change, which was then phonologized, and eventually lexicalized.

Comment: @AlexB: I think it would only have been a phonemic change if intervocalic /b/ had already been softened to [β] at this point. It seems hard to tell which of these sound changes came first.

Comment: @sumelic  Fair enough - didn't mean to nitpick! I asked because Weiss 2009 (2011) talks about **the w ~ β merger** in Vulgar Latin, which included **w > β** and **simultaneous b > β** (intervocalic position only) (Weiss 2009/2011, p. 512). Mergers are phonemic, aren't they?

Comment: @AlexB.: definitely. It's clear that these underwent a phonemic merger at some point, but I haven't seen any conclusive evidence dating the two contributing phonetic changes. They were "simultaneous" if you're looking at it from a broad historical viewpoint. I think most of our evidence actually comes from confusion in inscriptions though, which is a method that by its nature wouldn't be able to show non-phonemic changes that may have taken place earlier.

Comment: @Alex Do you know of any place on the web that talks about the w ~ β merger? That seems like the key to understanding what I asked about. Or at least the title of the Weiss book you referred to

Comment: @sumelic I assume you at least read Adams 2008, *The Regional Diversification of Latin 200 BC - AD 600*?

Comment: @Tom Weiss, Michael. 2009/2011. *Outline of the historical and comparative grammar of Latin.* Ann Arbor, Beech Stave Press. http://www.beechstave.com/weiss.htm

Comment: @AlexB.: No, I haven't. Sorry if I seem to be asserting things that I don't know. Is there actually clear evidence about the relative order of these sound changes?

Comment: @sumelic imho there's no clear evidence there about most things in historical linguistics. There's counter-evidence to everything I wrote here (and I dare say user6726).

Comment: Is it an accident that the Cyrillic letter "B" is equivalent to the Latin "V"? Was this fact true before the phonetic changes in Latin you talk about, and if it was, wasn't it really the cause? I mean, people could have confused the letter because in a different alphabet, one meant the other. Or, if Cyrillic were really made 800 years after the phonetic changes above ;-), wasn't the choice of the letters in Cyrillic script influenced by the confusion in Latin?

Comment: I think it is a half-coincidence. The Cyrillic fact derives from a sound change that Greek underwent where /b/ → [v], a change that Latin also enjoyed, Those are independent facts, but not totally coincidental since it is a common sound change.